# How to prevent duplicate numbers when trying to find combinations for something?

Tags: c, loops

I am trying to make a program that will the count of all multiple combinations of length, height and width of an object's volume.

I have created some loops that loop over all possible combinations but I don't know how to prevent multiples from appearing? For example, if 1x1x2 has already been found, I don't want to count 1x2x1. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int v, m = 0, k = 0;
    scanf("%d", &v); // a is length b is width c is height and v is volume
    for(int a=1;a<=v;a++){
        for(int b=1;b<v;b++){
            for(int c=1;c<v;c++){
                m = a*b*c;
                if(m == v){
                    k = k + 1; //k is the number of combinations
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The number of combinations was: %d", k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you also say "it should find all combination", but instead of *finding* them, you just count them. So, do you need to find the count, or do you need to generate a set with all them inside?

Comment: @MarcusMüller If you have code that is clearly C but it is an invalid C and coincidentally it happens to be valid C++, then it is not C. It is C++. You're complaining about namespaces but I rarely see people using `std::` for `scanf` and `printf` even in a code that is clearly C++. The code here is a valid C++ and it is unambiguously tagged as C++ so get over it and just treat it as C++. If you want, you may provide some advice on how to make it better.

Comment: Note that `int main()` isn't *strictly* valid C (should be `int main(void)`) - but it is perfectly valid C++.

Comment: @NO_NAME I really am just trying to get RandomCodeEnjoyer to get the answer that helps them; I've seen people tag things as C++ when they were actually looking for a C solution more than once; could you maybne not interfere with them getting the most out of my answer? thanks.

Comment: Just because this discussion is getting out of hand: the core question here is whether RandomCodeEnjoyer needs the count (in which case no loops are necessary at all, this is just combinatorics) or an actual container of tuples. If they need a container, then a C++ answer wouldn't help them if this is for interaction with C code (or actually C code), which is why I politely ask.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sorry for the confusion, im looking for a c answer. At my school we use a c++ ide but we use c libraries so Im just kinda used to writing with c libraries in c++.

Comment: and what with 1x1x8 vs 2X2X2 ?

Comment: Then I'm changing the includes to C and also the tag. No need to apologize!

Comment: Now, again for the more important question: do you need the *count* or an actual list of the resulting tuples?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I just need the count, my problem is that it includes duplicates in that count. I tried your previous answer but it didn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just said in a comment that you don't want to actually go through all these combinations; you just want their count.

That's even easier, because it's basic combinatorics: That's just the number of *k-combination with repetitions*; the number of such combinations is the *multiset coefficient*, which can be represented by a *binomial coefficient*, easy to compute, by

[image: ( n+k - 1) over k]

Here, n is the number of elements to choose from (that's `v` in your case!), and k is how many you choose, so that's 3.

So, all you need to do is write a C function that takes two numbers, n and k, and calculates (n+k-1+k)! / (n!·(n+k-1-k)!). I'm sure you can write a faculty function.

Comment: After reading it a few times, I understand what you've proposed but this answer could use a code snippet and maybe an example of the output.

Comment: @NO_NAME Indeed. *Especially* because of the confusion between the `<` and `<=` comparisons in the OP's three loop conditions.

Comment: @NO_NAME love to give that, but you'll notice that OP's code is more C than C++, so I asked them what language they'd like their answer in, and I haven't heard back yet!

Comment: I don't follow. The OP's code is definitely C++. It won't even compile as C. Also, the question is tagged C++. Now the code may not be *good* C++, but that' not particularly relevant.

Comment: @AdrianMole a has <= and the others have < because if one is equal to v the others cant be (e.x 1x1x10 = 10 so only one can be 10 and I happened to have chosen a)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I tried your answer but it doesn't seem to be working. Now it tries literally every possible combination that exists even if the product is way more than v. Also, to be honest, I am kinda new to programming so Im not sure what the difference is between c and cpp? Im using c libraries with c++, is that any different than using stdio.h with c?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Your answer worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Note that the problem is basically a factorization of a whole number, so that you can save a lot of iterations:

```c
int combinations(int volume)
{
    int k = 0;
    for ( int a = 1; a <= volume / a; ++a )
    { //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Up to the square root of volume
        if ( volume % a == 0 )
        { // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   Consider only the factors
            const int area = volume / a;
            for( int b = a; b <= area / b; ++b )
            {
                if ( area % b == 0 )
                {
                    const int length = area / b;               
                    printf("%d = %d * %d * %d\n", a * b * length, a, b, length);
                    ++k;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```